# How to get Dom tree in GeckoFX

Tags: c#, .net, geckofx

I started to play with GeckoFX. Unfortunately I didn't found any big documentation for that. I need to get DOM tree for the page. Iterate every element and get it's information. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example code:

```
GeckoElementCollection links = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (GeckoElement link in links) {
    Debug.WriteLine(link.GetAttribute("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an older question but someone may still be looking for an answer.

```
GeckoNodeCollection nodes = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("*");
foreach(GeckoNode node in nodes)
{
    //do whatever you need to do with the node .. 
    GeckoElement element = node as GeckoElement;
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nsIDOMNode` will provide you the DOM traversing ability. You can start from the Document node. You can look into the `nsInterfaces.cs` file for the interface details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XPath, you can try with this:

```
 browser.LoadXml("<MyTag><div>helloworld</div></MyTag>");

 var r = browser.Document.EvaluateXPath("//div");
 Assert.AreEqual(1, r.GetNodes().Count());
```

so in prev code:

```
GeckoElementCollection nodes = browser.Document.EvaluateXPath("//div").GetNodes();    
foreach(GeckoNode node in nodes)
{
    //do whatever you need to do with the node .. 
    GeckoElement element = node as GeckoElement;
    //..
}
```